# WSO2 Service Provider Not Listed

Tags: service, wso2, service-provider

I added a few **service providers** to my **WSO2 IS 5.0.0** instance but after a few days they were no longer listed. I am referring to **WSO2 Carbon** where you create the service providers.

Instead they appear as **roles**. They still work fine but since they do not appear under the **service provider list** I am unable to edit them.

Has anybody experienced this before? Is it possible to prevent them from disappearing or making them appear on the list once they've disappeared?

Answer (score 1):

We have not experienced such issue..  But please make sure following.  Once you create a Service provider, WSO2IS creates a role with a same name of the service provider.  User who are assigned to that role, can only see/edit the service provider.  Any other users who login to management console can not see/edit it. Therefore,  please make sure,  you are assigned that role correctly.  Also, if this is something intermittent, please try to restart the server and see whether you can see it.  As i know this Service provider object is kept in cache and not loaded from the database also.  I am not sure due to some issue with cache, service provider is disappear for sometimes.  But However,  you can login to the database of WSO2IS and verify the database entry.  Normally service providers and kept in `SP_APP`  table